# where to get data about all european cities, villages from?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, geography

I am looking for data about all european cities, villages and towns. Specifically I am interested in name, postal codes, telephone area codes, latitude, longitude, population and the country it belongs to.

**1. Where can I extract the most comprehensive amount of data from?**

**2. How to query data from LinkedGeoData**

To begin with, I tried to extract data from LinkedGeoData ( http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql ). However, I can't get any reasonable results. When the following query is executed, only the population occassionally appears, the other fields are always left blank.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
   ?place a <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/Place> .  
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/property/openGeoDB:name> ?name . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/openGeoDB:lat> ?lat . } 
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/openGeoDB:lon> ?lon . } 
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/property/openGeoDB:postal_codes> ?postal . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/openGeoDB:telephone_area_code> ?tel . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/population> ?population . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/openGeoDB:is_in_loc_id> ?inLocId . }

   ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/property/is_in> ?in. 
   FILTER ( REGEX(?in, "europe", "i") ) .
}
```

I noticed that all properties containing `openGeoDB` are blank, although the properties exist. So what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 4):

For finding appropriated datasets you may have a look at a dataset catalogue á la [the Data Hub](http://thedatahub.org/) or data Q&A boards á la [Get the Data](http://getthedata.org/).

Re. your second questions, it seems that the data at linkedgeodata seems to be a bit sparse, or one has to utilise other properties and/or classes. However, the following query seems to deliver at least some results, where you can see that every place in Europe can be addressed via the lgdb:is_in property

```
PREFIX lgd:<http://linkedgeodata.org/> 
PREFIX lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX lgdp:<http://linkedgeodata.org/property/> 
PREFIX lgdoogdb: <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/openGeoDB> 
PREFIX lgdpogdb: <http://linkedgeodata.org/property/openGeoDB> 

SELECT * 
FROM <http://linkedgeodata.org> 
WHERE 
{
   ?place a lgdo:Place .  
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdpogdb:name ?name . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdoogdb:lat ?lat . } 
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdoogdb:lon ?lon . } 
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdpogdb:postal_codes ?postal . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdoogdb:telephone_area_code ?tel . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdo:population ?population . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdoogdb:is_in_loc_id ?inLocId . }
   OPTIONAL { ?place lgdp:is_in ?in . }
}
LIMIT 100
```

with e.g. the following query you could explore the dataset's structure a bit:

```
PREFIX lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT * 
FROM <http://linkedgeodata.org> 
WHERE 
{
   ?place a lgdo:Place .  
   ?place rdfs:label ?label .
}
LIMIT 100
```

... and finally the following query returns 100 places in Europe:

```
PREFIX lgdo:<http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT * 
FROM <http://linkedgeodata.org> 
WHERE 
{
    ?place a lgdo:Place .
    ?place rdfs:label ?label .  
    ?place <http://linkedgeodata.org/property/is_in%3Acontinent> "Europe" .
    FILTER ( lang(?label) = "" )
}
LIMIT 100
```

Please note the FILTER expression is for filtering out every language specific label that has an language tag, i.e., plain literals will be displayed with that query.